# Two-Way on Datagridview and SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

Is there any way to, in a Winform application, detect outside changes in a SQL Server table during a view/edit on a Datagridview?

We have 2 offices here (each one in a different city) and very often people are seeing/editing the same SQL Server table, using a Datagridview binded directly to the database using Dataset, TableAdapter and BindingSource controls.

If some guy outside here changes some record, it WOULD be suppressed from my Datagridview, indicating it is not available anymore. But it doesn't, until I close and reload the form...

My question: I don't want neither to attach the `Rebind()` or `ResetBinding()` methods in a time-based routine, nor have to re-plot the entire datagridview listing.  Is there any way to Datagridview detect automatically the change performed by other system in the SQL Server table?

In other words, can I have a "two-way" rebind mode in that case?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: There isn't any automatic solution for the problem. But there are some solutions to implement. For example you can use [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7(v=vs.90).aspx) to detect changes. Also you can use WCF or [SignalR](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b) to push notifications to clients.

Comment: Thank you @RezaAghaei. I would like to automate the function and not utilize parallel programming to comply it. Thanks anyway.